# Jquery is working in firefox but not in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I have the following code that works in Firefox but not in IE:

```
if ($('#interuptedClaim')) {
                $(".removeHref li a,.removeHref li a:hover").removeAttr("href").css({
                    "cursor": "default",
                    "color": "grey"
                });
            }
            $('#frontPageCancelButton').bind('click', function () {
                $('#interuptedClaim').hide();
                $('#enter-new-claim-menu-link').attr('href', 'create_claim.htm');
                $('#resolve-deferral-menu-link').attr('href', 'resolve_deferral_selection_criteria.htm');
                $('#update-pended-claim-menu-link').attr('href', 'update_pended_claim.htm');
                $('#adjust-claim-menu-link').attr('href', 'adjust_claim.htm');
                $('#adjust-subrogation-menu-link').attr('href', 'adjust_subrogation.html');
                $('#void-claim-menu-link').attr('href', 'void_claim.htm');
                $('#refund-processing-menu-link').attr('href', 'refund_processing.html');
                $('#update-claim-menu-link').attr('href', 'update_claim.html');
                $('#reopen-denial-menu-link').attr('href', 'reopen_denial.htm');
                $(".removeHref li a").css({
                    "font-weight": "bold",
                    "cursor": "pointer",
                    "text-decoration": "none",
                    "color": "#000"
                });
                $("#sidebar a:hover").css({
                    "font-weight": "bold",
                    "cursor": "pointer",
                    "text-decoration": "none"
                });
                $(".removeHref li a.active").css({
                    "font-weight": "bold",
                    "cursor": "pointer",
                    "text-decoration": "none",
                    "color": "#9E0B0F"
                });
                $('removeHreF li a:hover').addClass('linkHover');
            });
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Be more specific and clear!Is script showing any error?

Comment: $('#interuptedClaim') is always true no? you should use $('#interuptedClaim').length

Comment: Your first if test will always be true - you probably want to test the .length property instead. Also, please specify which version(s) of IE it doesn't work for. I suspect it may be the ":hover".

Comment: Also, I believe you are missing a closing brace for that if. Maybe that's why IE is choking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the code, you have `$('removeHreF li a:hover')`. There should be a `.` at the beginning of that selector.

Like this : `$('.removeHreF li a:hover').addClass('linkHover');`